# Class 'Eloquent' not found when mocking in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm following through Jeffrey Way's Laravel Testing Decoded and I've hit an issue I can't seem to fix.

I'm actually work through this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/testing-laravel-controllers/ Which is an excerpt from his book.

Basically I have a test like so:

```
class PostsTest extends TestCase {


    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Post');        
    }
```

And that like for mocking Eloquent and Post returns:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Eloquent' not found
```

When I run phpunit. Incidentally if I use Jeffrey's Laravel Generators and just generate some scaffold e.g.

```
php artisan generate:scaffold post --fields="title:string, body:string"
```

And run phpunit I get same error. He's using the same:

```
$this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Post');
```

To mock the classes. Does anyone have any suggestions on what the issue could be?

---

I've been working through the tutorial again from scratch and am still getting the same error. I've pushed it to a public repo so people can see: https://github.com/RyanHavoc/tdd-laravel

Just pull it down, run composer install/update and phpunit.

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to the issue.

```
//Causes the Class 'Eloquent' not found error
public function __construct()
{
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Post');
}

//Setting the mocks in the setUp() method instead works
public function setUp() 
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Post');
}
```